# How to know error has happened when using make -k

Tags: makefile

I want to log every error on building code.
so I can use `-k` to make it keep-going even error happened.

However, could I know some error has happened, 
and it is `-k` to make it continue?

I know I can check some pattern error message like `make: ***`.
But I still wondering if I can have some message in log like:
"error happened, keep-going to make" when I have `-k`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make reports errors on its output/error for human readers. Other computer programs can check its exit status, which should be non-zero if any error has occurred. If you're calling make from a shell script, you could do something similar to

```
make -k || echo "BAD: ERROR(S)"
```

except change echo to something that's actually useful for you. Other ways to call make will have similar options.

Comment: But, since I use -k, the last target may be make successfully. so I can not use the final status to check, right?

Comment: make should report whether there has been any error at all, not whether there was an error in the last target. It does so for me, does it behave differently for you? If so, which make are you using?

Comment: The first time you run that, make will end with "Target `all' not remade because of errors.", and a non-zero exit status. The second time, there won't be any error at all: make won't try to recreate hello, because hello already exists and is newer than hello.c. If you want to know if make has ever failed, record the exit status each time you call make.

Comment: sorry, I made a wrong example.. I want to make a example is that the last target does not depend not the middle target but has error. Like to build android whole source. the final output are boot.img system.img, /etc. but something error when making boot.img, it keep-going to make system.img successfully. something like this. I will try more, and thanks your quick suggestion.

Comment: If you have an example that's a bit smaller than Android, I'll be happy to take a look.